# CSS: How to align table data

Tags: html, css, alignment, frontend, css-tables

[image]

How to align BDS to education? Without using white-space:nowrap.

```
<div class="doc-schedule clearfix">
  <p>
    <table style="border: 0px;border-style: none">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Speciality</strong></td>
        <td class="tdPadding"><span>{{ page.dentist_specialty }}</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Education</strong></td>
        <td class="tdPadding"><span>{{ page.dentist_education }}</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Work Days</strong></td>
        <td class="tdPadding"><span>{{ page.dentist_workdays }}</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </p>
</div>
........
```

Comment: Please add the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr` are vertically aligned middle by default

add this

```
tr {
  vertical-align:top
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6xaczgba/)